# jqueryvalidation show error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I am using jquery validation plug-in for form validations(http://jqueryvalidation.org/).
I have two passoword boxes which expected to be equal.
I want to show an error message after the second password box when these are not equal.
Sometimes , error message is not shown . Do I need to handle this in Submit button onclick action?
Looks like this is kind of duplication. Please help me to debug or fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add some code or a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Call [validate()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) when the cursor loses focus on the second password field by using [jQuery.blur()](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)  and also when submitting the form in case of pressing the enter button. You can listen to the submit event by using the [jQuery.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Example of listening to submit:

```
jQuery.on("submit",function(){
   $("form").validate();
   //return false to cancel submission.
});
```

Also make this idiot proof by validating the data server side for user's that are not using javascript, like (Google) bots.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use it like this:

```
<form id="myform">
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input id="password" name="password" />
<br/>
<label for="password_again">Again</label>
<input class="left" id="password_again" name="password_again" />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    password: "required",
    password_again: {
      equalTo: "#password"
    }
  }
});
</script>
```